# When getting Document object from Word.Application object, its members are not filled from gencache cache while VBSEdit is able to get them

Tags: python, ms-word, com, win32com

https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2004-October/002582.html summarizes my problem perfectly (with slight edits to update it for my case):

> I would like to have a Word Document instance with all methods and
>   properties visible during interactive session.  This is my currnet
>   apporach:
>
> ```
> >>> from win32com.client import gencache, Dispatch
> >>> gencache.EnsureModule('{00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}', 0, 8, 1, bForDemand=True) 
> <module 'win32com.gen_py.00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x8x1' from
> 'C:\DOCUME~1\osuchw\LOCALS~1\Temp\gen_py\2.3\00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x8x1\__init__.py'>
> >>> word = Dispatch('Word.Application')
> >>> word 
> <win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library._Application instance at 0x18074720>
> >>> doc = word.Documents.Add()
> >>> doc 
> <win32com.gen_py.None.Document>
> ```
>
> As you can see I am getting a dynamic object not knowing its
>   methods/properties. What I would like to get is something like:
>
> ```
> >>> doc = Dispatch('Word.Document')
> >>> doc 
> <win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library._Document instance at 0x37038040>
> ```

I guess I need to also generate a wrapper from another type library (e.g. there is "Office 12.0 Object Library") but there's no hint on which it is. Likewise, there's no `TypeLib` subkey at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{00020906-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}` which is what `doc.CLSID` produces.

The only answer in that thread directs to RTFM a general book on Word programming w/o any hints whatsoever (I seriously doubt it even mentions typelibs).

I ended up generating wrappers for all the type libraries at the machine with the following code:

```
import win32com.client.selecttlb    
ii=win32com.client.selecttlb.EnumTlbs()
ii=[i.desc for i in ii]
# one typelib - "Visual Basic runtime objects and procedures [6.0]" - produced an error
for i in ii: subprocess.call(['python','-m','win32com.client.makepy',i])
```

but even in this case, it's still `win32com.gen_py.None.Document`.

---

The strangest thing is that the object's class *is* recognized and present in the cache:

```
>>> ad=win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Word.Document")
>>> d = w.ActiveDocument
>>> d.__class__
<class win32com.gen_py.00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x8x4.Document at 0x02A101B8>
>>> ad.__class__
<class win32com.gen_py.00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x8x4._Document at 0x02A07B20>
>>> len(dir(ad.__class__))
141
>>> len(dir(d.__class__))
11
```

At the same time, VBA editor and [VBSEdit](http://www.vbsedit.com/) list `w.ActiveDocument`'s members just fine. How do they do that and why can't `pythoncom` do the same?

Comment: Word 2013 VBA uses `Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\MSWORD.OLB` and `Program Files\ Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE15\MSO.DLL`.  I'm guessing the former is where `Document` lives.

Comment: @cxw no difference. `python -m win32com.client.makepy "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\MSWORD.OLB"` produces the same wrapper as `python -m win32com.client.makepy "Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library"`.

Comment: 32- or 64-bit?  On my system, `ad.CLSID` is `0002096B-...` instead of `00020906-...`, and the former lives under `HKCR\Wow6432Node`.  I can repro with Office 2013 32-bit and Python 3.4 64-bit.  If your Office and Python are different bit widths, would you please try a Python with the same width as your Office and see if it helps?

Comment: @cxw both Office and Python are 32-bit. Office 2007 and Python 2.7.13 with pywin32-221 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`d._dispobj_` has all the members, so it can be used instead of `d`.

The immediate problem is solved.

Yet I've still no idea what is going on.